# SQL query to select up to N records per criteria

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was wondering if it's possible to use SQL (preferably snowflake) to select up to N records given certain criteria.
To illustrate:
Lets say I have a table with 1 million records, containing full names and phone numbers.

There's no limits on the amount of phone numbers that can be assigned to X person, but I only want to select up to 10 numbers per person, even if the person has more than 10.

Notice I don't want to select just 10 records, I want the query to return every name in the table, I only want to ignore extra phone numbers when the person already has 10 of them.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use window functions to solve this greatest-n-per-group problem:

```
select t.*
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by name order by phone_number) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 10
```

Note that you need an ordering column to define what "top 10" actually means. I assumed `phone_number`, but you can change that to whatever suits your use case best.

Better yet: as commented by waldente, snowflake has the `qualify` syntax, which removes the need for a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
qualify row_number() over(partition by name order by phone_number) <= 10
```

Comment: In Snowflake you can use QUALIFY instead of where, and eliminate the subquery

Answer (score 2):

This query will help your requirement:

```
select 
    full_name,
    phonenumber 
from 
    (select 
        full_name, 
        phonenumber, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by phonenumber order by  full_name desc) as ROW_NUMBER from sample_tab) a 
where 
    a.row_number between 1 and 10 
order by 
    full_name asc,
    phonenumber desc;
```

using Snowflake Qualify function:

```
select 
    full_name, 
    phonenumber 
from 
    sample_tab qualify row_number() over (partition by phonenumber order by full_name) between 1 and 10 
order by 
    full_name asc ,
    phonenumber desc;
```